# Updating model without scope in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I have been searching for answers for several hours and I think I need to add a separate question. I have the following table and controller:

```
<table class="table table-striped">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>value</th>
          <th>datapoint</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tr ng-repeat="obj in cont.objs">
          <td>{{ obj.value }}</td>
          <td>{{ obj.datapoint }}</td>
      </tr>
</table>
<button>Next</button>
```

---

objects.controller.js

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app.objects')
        .controller('ObjectsController', ObjectsController );

    ObjectsController.$inject = ['objectsService', '$state', '$stateParams', '$uibModal', 'logger'];

    function ObjectsController(objectsService, $state, $stateParams, $uibModal, logger) {
        var cont = this;

        activate().then( function successCallback(selectObjects) {
            cont.objects = loadObjects(selectObjects._links.objects.href);
      });
    }

    function loadObjects(uri) {
     ...
        cont.objects = getObjects(uri)
        return cont.objects;
    }
...
```

I have a button 'Next' and when pressed, needs to update cont.objects by fetching new cont.objects from the api by calling loadObjects with the original uri + '/2'.

I thought maybe

```
<button ng-click="cont.loadObjects(cont.objects.next.href)">Next</button>
```

would work, but I get an error saying loadObjects is undefined. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope you had defined activate() function and to make this work use 
controller As with the controller definition and make sure you are clicking the button after the success of activate() function .
https://toddmotto.com/digging-into-angulars-controller-as-syntax/

Answer (score 0):

You're not binding that function to scope. You need to add that function inside of your controller and bind it.

```
function ObjectsController(objectsService, $state, $stateParams, $uibModal, logger) {
  var cont = this;
  cont.loadObjects = loadObjects;

  function loadObjects(uri) {
    cont.objects = getObjects(uri)
    return cont.objects;
  } 

  activate().then(function successCallback(selectObjects) {
    cont.objects = loadObjects(selectObjects._links.objects.href);
  });
}
```